# Serialization of Try/Success/Failure in Scala Akka

Tags: scala, akka-cluster, akka-typed

I am trying to `ask` an actor which would reply with a Try:

```
val reply = actor.ask[Try[MyReply]](MyCommand)
```

However when reply comes from an actor on another node in the cluster I get following error in logs:

```
Failed to serialize message [scala.util.Success].
```

Interestingly enough, if I use `Option` instead of `Try` things seem to work fine. I want to use `Try` for better errors control. Is there a way to achieve this with a `Try`?

Comment: All message's that are supposed to be sent over the network are required to be serializable. `Try` is not.

Comment: Which serializer are you using? The default is a Java serializer, which obviously cannot serialize `Try`. You can see at [serialization](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization.html) by Akka how to override the default serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is done on purpose by developers of akka to avoid usage of `Try` as transfer types.

`Try` is designed to handle all non fatal exceptions. And this will require you to serialise exceptions so they are to be transferred over network and handled on other node. Imo, an exception must be handled locally.

If you wish to transfer your business errors, I'd suggest to use `Either[MyError, MyReply]` instead, where `MyError` can be your own `case class` defining specific business errors.

Edit:

As @artur suggested, you can also use [akka.pattern.StatusReply](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#generic-response-wrapper) to notify back error messages.

```scala
case class Command(replyTo: ActorRef[StatusReply[MyReply]])

val actorRef: ActorRef[Command] = ???
actorRef.askWithStatus(Command).onComplete {
  case Success(response) =>
  case Failure(StatusReply.ErrorMessage(text)) => ???
  case Failure(_) => ???
}
```

Comment: There's also  `akka.pattern.StatusReply` (at least in ver `2.6.10`) that has a built in serializer and can be used for  signaling errors.

Comment: Thanks, guys. It looks exactly like what I needed. Somehow I missed this from the documentation.